# How to fix replaying transitions in d3 v4?

Tags: d3.js

I'm implementing a chart using d3 that has a sliding x axis. [Demo](http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/dNpRzK?editors=0010)

The problem is, when I change to another tab, and then go back (say after 10 seconds), d3 seems to try to replay the missing transitions, which results in a very awkward behavior of the axis. See [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1893981/d3-transition-replay.gif).

Mike Bostock [mentions that](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488#9789):

> D3 4.0 fixes this problem by changing the definition of time. Transitions don’t typically need to be synchronized with absolute time; transitions are primarily perceptual aids for tracking objects across views. D3 4.0 therefore runs on perceived time, which only advances when the page is in the foreground. When a tab is backgrounded and returned to the foreground, it simply picks up as if nothing had happened.

Is this really fixed? Am I doing anything wrong?

```js
const timeWindow = 10000;
const transitionDuration = 3000;

const xScaleDomain = (now = new Date()) =>
  [now - timeWindow, now];

const totalWidth = 500;
const totalHeight = 200;
const margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};
const width = totalWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = totalHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select('.chart')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

svg
  .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

// Add x axis
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(xScaleDomain(new Date() - transitionDuration))
  .range([0, width]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const xAxisSelection = svg
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);

// Animate
const animate = () => {
  xScale.domain(xScaleDomain());

  xAxisSelection
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionDuration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .call(xAxis)
    .on('end', animate);
};

animate();
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

rect {
  fill: #fff;
  outline: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@4.4.1/build/d3.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not D3 transitions. The problem here is `new Date()`.

Every time you go to another tab, the transition pauses. So far, so good. But when you come back to the chart, let's say, after 20 seconds, you get a new date that's the current date... however your `timeWindow` is the same, as well as your `transitionDuration`:

```
const timeWindow = 10000;
const transitionDuration = 3000;

const xScaleDomain = (now = new Date()) => [now - timeWindow, now];
```

That makes the axis jump ahead faster, because the difference between the old and new values at any point in the domain is not 3 seconds anymore.

Here is a very simple solution, too crude and requiring improvements, just to show you that the problem is `new Date()`. In this *solution* (again, far from perfect), I manually set the date in each animation to jump 10 seconds, no matter how long you stay in another tab:

```
var t = xScale.domain()[1];
t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);

xScale.domain([xScale.domain()[1], t]);
```

Here is the CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrjMxy?editors=0010

A better solution, using your code, would be changing `timeWindow` and `transitionDuration` to take into consideration the difference between the new `new Date()` and the old `new Date()` (that is, how long the user has been in another tab).

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Does d3 provide hooks for "transition paused" and "transition resumes" so that I could measure the difference in time?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't think it natively does, but you can create your own function.